# Change default Android emulator when debugging Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, windows-7-x64

I installed `VS2017` a few days ago, created the simple app [Build your first Xamarin Forms App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows), and now I want to debug.

I am having issues with the default Android emulator created by the `VS2017` installation (`Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo`) so I created a new emulator. This is the screenshot.

How can I change the default so it debugs in the newly-created emulator?

I wanted to point out that I'm new to all of this, so I would like to run it without having to install anything else. I would like to see *something* run before I install anything else.

I also wanted to point out that I've tried clicking on "Start" on either one of them when not in debug mode, and I get `Could not start emulator. Unable to load DLL 'DismApi'` error.

The only way it automatically starts is if I hit `F5` and the emulator window pops up. Then I go to *Tools* > *Android Device Manager* and the default emulator says "Stop" (it's running). If I click on "Stop" and then press "Start", I will get the same error again: `Could not start emulator. Unable to load DLL 'DismApi'`.

[image]

Comment: Just start that device, when you tap Run, the visual studio detects the device that is running and deploys the code there.

Comment: I edited my question, but it seems I cannot start it manually. It only starts when I click `F5` and I debug the app.

Answer (score 0):

Where you launch the debugger just click the arrow pointing down to open the dropdown. Then select you new device. It will stay as you default device. Please see the image for reference:

[image]

Note: You may have to restart Visual Studio for your new device to appear.